# Sitecore EXM 3.4 Update 1 connectivity error

Tags: exm

I have installed EXM 3.4 update 1 on clean Sitecore 8.2 update 2 instance. After completion of post installation steps I am getting below exceptions in log files.

```
Exception: Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Exceptions.ConnectivityException
Message: Failed to retrieve session information from the session data provider.
Source: Sitecore.ExM.Framework
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions.EnvironmentReader.GetSessions(Boolean includeSessionData, Boolean includeRuntimeData, Boolean includeStatistics, Boolean onlyActive, Nullable`1 expirationTimeLimit)
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions.EnvironmentReader.GetSessionsByOwner(Boolean includeSessionData, Boolean includeRuntimeData, Boolean includeStatistics)
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions.Environment.Maintain()
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions.Session.OnSessionUpdateEvent()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
Message: Cannot open database "Sitecore_EXM" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'sa'.
Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.DataProviders.SqlSessionDataProvider.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetSessions>b__0()
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.DataProviders.SqlUtil.InvokeWithDeadlockRetry[TReturn](Func`1 function, Int32 maxNumberOfAttempts)
   at Sitecore.ExM.Framework.Distributed.Sessions.EnvironmentReader.GetSessions(Boolean includeSessionData, Boolean includeRuntimeData, Boolean includeStatistics, Boolean onlyActive, Nullable`1 expirationTimeLimit)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the installation guide on [the download page](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Email_Experience_Manager/Email_Experience_Manager_34/Email_Experience_Manager_34_Update1.aspx) in step 3 of the installation process:

> In the App_Config/ConnectionStrings.config file of your Sitecore
>   solution, update the exm.master and the exm.web SQL server connection
>   strings. For example:
>
> ```
> <add name="exm.master" connectionString="user id=user;password=password;Data
> Source=(server);Database=Sitecore_EXM" />
> <add name="exm.web" connectionString="user id=user;password=password;Data
> Source=(server);Database=Sitecore_EXM.WEB"/>
> ```

**Please note** that these are just **example** connection strings, and that you will have to change the user id, password and database name to match your setup.

Comment: Even adding these connection string will not help. We also need to rename the databases as default sitecore databases for EXM are attached as Sitecore81_EXM Sitecore81_EXM_Web instead of Sitecore_EXM and Sitecore_EXM.WEB

Comment: That's why it says "For example" ;)

Comment: I agree however if someone dumb like me, now he might get help from this question. ;)

Comment: Fair enough :) I added a note to clarify

Comment: And I have marked it as Answer!

Answer (score 0):

This is because when you attached Sitecore `Sitecore_EXM` and `Sitecore_EXM_WEB` databases in SQL Server. They get attached as **Sitecore81_EXM** and **Sitecore81_EXM_WEB**, so database names in connection string config and attached databases is mismatched. Either Rename your `exm` databases in config file to match exactly same as attached dbs in SQL server or rename SQL server dbs to match exactly same as per config file to fix this issue.
Hope this helps!